# Calling a constructor in another constructor (and getting the modified variables from cons.1)

Tags: java, class, constructor, this, instance

I searched the web but did not find my answers. Here is my question.
The goal here is to use my verifications (if codeForme<0 || codeforme>9)... etc only in my first constructor, because my two other constructors are calling the first one.

But, when i enter for example codeforme = 20 in my second constructor, it is not modified as it should be after running the first constructor. I know the problem is probably from the this.codeForme = forme because it takes my parameter's forme instead of the codeForme from the first. 
There should be an easy way, thanks!

Here is my code so far:

```
public class carteMere {

    // variable(s) de classe s'il y a lieu
    private static int identifiant = 0;
    // variable(s) d'instance s'il y a lieu
    private String marque;
    private int codeForme = 0;
    private int capaciteMaxMemoire = 8;
    private int memoireInstalle = 0;
    private int codeCarte;
    // constructeur(s) s'il y a lieu
    public carteMere( String marque,
                      int codeForme,
                      int capaciteMaxMemoire,
                      int memoireInstalle) {
        this.marque = marque;
        this.identifiant = identifiant+1;
        this.codeCarte=this.identifiant;
        if(codeForme < 0 || codeForme > 9){
            codeForme = 0;
        }
        if(capaciteMaxMemoire<=0){
            capaciteMaxMemoire = 8;
        }
        if(memoireInstalle < 0){
            memoireInstalle = 0;
        }else if (memoireInstalle> capaciteMaxMemoire){
            memoireInstalle = capaciteMaxMemoire;
        }
        codeForme = codeForme;
        capaciteMaxMemoire = capaciteMaxMemoire;
        memoireInstalle = memoireInstalle;
    }
    public carteMere(int forme, int capaciteMax, int memoireInstalle){
        this("ASUS", forme, capaciteMax, memoireInstalle);
        this.codeForme = forme;
        this.capaciteMaxMemoire = capaciteMax;
        this.memoireInstalle = memoireInstalle;
        this.codeCarte=this.identifiant;
    }
    public carteMere(int codeForme, int memoireInstalle){
        this(codeForme, 8, memoireInstalle);
        this.codeForme=codeForme;
        this.memoireInstalle=memoireInstalle;
        this.identifiant = identifiant;
        this.codeCarte=this.identifiant;
    }
```

Edit:

If I do:
carte1 = new carteMere(10, 8);

Then I inspect carte1, the codeForme is 10, and it should be 0 because it should have been modifed in the 1st constructor.

Comment: Is there a way to pass through the verifications of the first constructor when I use the 2nd (this one calls the first). Or I just copy paste these if/else ?
Thank you

Comment: You first should be coherent with your naming : codeForme and forme are used for the same parameter in your different constructors, which is a bit confusing and hard to read. You also should always use "this" when setting your instance variables, which you don't at the end of 1st constructor. Maybe with just this you will be able to read your code better and understand what is happening

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` to qualify your instance variables as you have done for `marque`, `indentifiant`, and `codeCarte`.  Also use `else` on your `if`s to assign the variable the normal value if not outside the validation range.  E.g. for `codeForme`:

```
if(codeForme < 0 || codeForme > 9) {
    this.codeForme = 0;
}
else {
    this.codeForme = codeForme;
}
```

And similarly for `capaciteMaxMemoire` and `memoireInstalle`.

Comment: Thank you,  but it doesn't resolve the problem i still can't find a way to get the right modified variable when calling the second or third constructor.

Comment: Let the first constructor do all the work of assigning the instance variables.  It can't modify the arguments passed in by the other constructors because it gets passed copies of those variables.  Modifying those values in the first constructor would only modify the local copies, so the changes can't show up in the values in the other constructors.  In your other constructors, where you call the first constructor with `this`, remove the lines that attempt to assign values to instance variables; let the first constructor assign everything.

Comment: So there is no way to skip having to code the same verifications if/else in other constructors?

Comment: I wouldn't say that.  Just have the first constructor do all the verifications and instance variable assignments, so that it doesn't matter that the other constructors' parameter values aren't changed.

Comment: Yes, i managed to make it work and thanks to you.
I had to delete the this. in my if/else.
This. in every instance assignments of the first constructors.
And the 2 other constructors have only this(x,y,z,etc.);
voila